# 2021 4Runner broken into. Person left a multi tool and an easy flo spout inside. Vandalism or theft?

Tags: fuel-system, fuel-tank, 4runner

My 2021 4Runner was broken into. The rear window was all smashed and the person left an easy flo spout accessory and a bike multi-tool inside

[image: Easy Flo Spout Accessory]

[image: Multi Tool]

My initial suspicion was gas theft but when I read more about easy flo spout accessory, I understand that it is used with flow out of the can and not into it. Therefore I now suspect that the person may have used it to put some substance into my fuel tank.

I can't know if any fuel was stolen because I don't remember the fuel levels I had.

I drove forth and back a few feet and the engine sounded normal but I don't want to risk driving as far as the mechanic to get it inspected without knowing for sure if the fuel tank is clean. Any advice here would be appre

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the purpose of the break-in was to look for valuables. And then by a thief who isn't very proficient. If this was an attempt to vandalize your vehicle, someone would do it *quietly*, meaning, they'd do the deed and not leave much of a trace behind. As far as what was left behind, the tool could be the tool which was used to break the rear window. Who knows what the spout was to do for them.

Still, jwh20 has a point about your fuel. You can have it tested, or just have it removed and replaced with fresh. Still might be your best course of action.

Answer (score 0):

Without testing the fuel there is not really any way to know.

My recommendation would have been to have the fuel drained out and replaced with fresh fuel, and that still may be a good idea at this point.  You may have caused some damage by driving it around with something added but there are many variables.